# Reading data from a binary file and storing it in a structure yields a segmentation fault

Tags: c, file-io, file, segmentation-fault, structure

I'm having problems with a 'segmentation fault' error.

I'm reading data from a binary file, which I'm trying to store in a structure; here's the code to what I'm doing or 'trying' to do:

```
struct Medico //users are medics
{
  int Id_Doctor; //Id User
  int Estado; //status of the user
  char Nombre[60]; //name of the user
  char Clave_Acceso[20]; //password of the user
  char Especialidad[40]; //especialty of the user
  struct Medico *next;
};

void Cargar_Datos () //load files
{
  FILE *Archivaldo; ///file- Archivo means file
  struct Medico * head = NULL;
  struct Medico * prev, *current;
  char especialida[40], password[20]; ///locals for specialty and password
  char nombre_doc[60]; ///local for name
  int estado_doc, id_doc; // local for status 

  if((Archivaldo=fopen("md.dat", "a+b"))==NULL)
    {
      printf("No se pudo abrir el archivo de Medicos\n");
      exit(1);
    }
  rewind(Archivaldo);
  current = (struct Medico *) malloc (sizeof(struct Medico));

  fread(&id_doc, sizeof(int), 1, Archivaldo);
  fread(nombre_doc, sizeof(char), sizeof(nombre_doc), Archivaldo);
  fread(password, sizeof(char), 20 , Archivaldo);
  fread(especialida, sizeof(char), 40, Archivaldo);
  fread(&estado_doc, sizeof(int), 1, Archivaldo);

  printf("ID: %d\n", id_doc);
  printf("\nDoctor: ");
  puts(nombre_doc);
  printf("\nPassword: ");
  puts(password);
  printf("\nEspecialidad: ");
  puts(especialida);
  printf("\nEstado: ");
  if(estado_doc==1)
    puts("Activo\n");
  else
    puts("Inactivo\n");
  current->Id_Doctor=id_doc;
  strcpy(current->Nombre, nombre_doc); 
  strcpy(current->Clave_Acceso, password); 
  strcpy(current->Especialidad, especialida);
  current->Estado=estado_doc; 
  current=current->next;

  fclose(Archivaldo);

}
```

Comment: Please reformat your message so that the code has proper indentation. Right now it's unreadable.

Comment: Please also try and cut down your examples to the smallest bit of code that will reproduce the bug (this is good debugging technique in any case).  And specify exactly where the segfault is happening (find this by running it in a debugger).

Comment: @Reese: thanks. Now what we are missing is the rest of the program...

Comment: The way those fread() calls are used is extremely error prone depending on the md.dat contents. Right now I suspect that one of the puts() calls is used on an unterminated string.

Comment: I don't like playing cop, but I really do find people that cannot stick to a single account annoying: http://stackoverflow.com/users/531509/ro-schz http://stackoverflow.com/users/523300/jujitsu2 http://stackoverflow.com/users/520962/jujitsu Especially when it's done so that the new account is not burdened with a whole pile of negative reputation.

Comment: @thkala I hate to play the fugitive; but im new to this and I actually didnt know I was gonna keep asking questions in this site.. I dont even know why I got bad reputation. I just asked two questions(which I didnt even comment back)..I believe this is gonna be my definitive account. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @Ro Schz: The reason you got downvoted in your previous questions was because you made it damn hard for us to help you. You dumped a pile of code on us and said "please help me". You did not explain what exactly the code is supposed to do, how exactly it fails or what you tried to debug your problem. For example, even if you don't know how to use a debugger, a bunch of printfs in the code above would go a long way to pinpoint where the segmentation fault happens.

Comment: haha. true that and im sorry for that; (from now on)Ill try to be as explicit as I can; Im sorry; im the worst trying to explain myself :/

Comment: Also when you post code, please indent it correctly and add comments to it. You should remember that many (most?) of the people here do not speak Spanish (is it Spanish ?). Having a pile of code with seemingly random function and variable names is an added obstacle if there are no comments or at least a decent explanation of its purpose.

Comment: Sure, totally agree with you. How can I make it so when I post the code appears in a 'viewable' format??
I'll edit the code right now

Comment: Right now the format is OK - some good people around here fixed it. But when you do post code again, indent it properly, mark it and use the 101010  button in the StackOVerflow editor to indicate that it's code and it should be left as-is.

Comment: Something else that is quite important: You would help us help you more (sic), if you stripped down your code to an _executable_ program. The code above has obvious style, practice and structure issues , but we cannot easily help you with your specific problem because we cannot compile and run it ourselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to debug a segmentation fault is to use a debugger such as GDB or a memory analyser such as Valgrind.

If one is not available, it usually helps to add numbered printf() statements in the code. When you find the last printf() that was executed before the error, you can add more printf() statements and repeat your tests to narrow it down.

A few common causes of a segmentation fault in C program:

- Trying to dereference a NULL pointer. That often happens if said pointer is the result of a function call such as malloc() or fopen(), whose output was not checked for errors before proceeding.
- Going beyond the edges of an array or allocated block. Strings that are not null-terminated properly are a common cause of this. If printing a string produces garbage in the screen, this could be the cause.
- Trying to use a memory block that has already been freed with free().

Answer (score 3):

You are reading `nombre_doc`, `especialida` and all other strings with `fread`. This is fine but it does not terminate the strings with a `'\0'` character. You use `puts` and `strcpy` which are expecting these strings to end with the nul-terminator.

First, increase the size of the strings with 1. After that terminate your strings:

```
nombre_doc[60] = '\0';
```

Comment: Uh that will go past the end of the array. You wanted 59 not 60.

Comment: Thats why I said he'd have to increase the size of the string with one. I assume he has fixed-width fields in the file.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you do change the length of `nombre_doc`, you'll have to adjust the `fread` call a little.

Comment: Steve: Not if you increase the length by one, as suggested :)

Comment: Lets cope with what you just said; is it even posible to modify the size of a string previously defined??
Where I believe the error lies is here:
'
current->Id_Doctor=id_doc;
  strcpy(current->Nombre, nombre_doc);
  strcpy(current->Clave_Acceso, password);
  strcpy(current->Especialidad, especialida);
  current->Estado=estado_doc;
  current=current->next;
'

Comment: @Ro no. But I meant you should add one to the size of your strings in the source. I.e. have `char Nombre[61]` in your struct.

Comment: @terminus Ok, I see where you're going; so Ill modify every string in the struct; shouldnt I?

Comment: @Ro Yes, that's one option. There are better solutions to your problem, but this way is very simple.

Comment: @terminus ok, I tried adding 1 to the size ; and just added before the 'current->bla bla bla' something like nombre_doc[60] = '\0';
but the 'segmentation fault' error still comes up

Comment: @Ro did you do it for every string you use?

Comment: @Ro: I'll be honest with you: If I had this code in my hands I'd rewrite it from scratch. Since this is not an option (you probably don't know any different and we should not do it for you), can you do us all a favour and spread a few printf("I'm here at line 777\n"); around so that we can find where the segfault happens? Have you tried using a debugger (useful things those debuggers).

Comment: Totally agree with you, its just a program Im trying to do to understand what every function does;
Yes I added some printf's and right before the
current->Id_Doctor=id_doc;
  strcpy(current->Nombre, nombre_doc); 
  strcpy(current->Clave_Acceso, password); 
  strcpy(current->Especialidad, especialida);
  current->Estado=estado_doc; 
  current=current->next;

Comment: @Ro: Please add more printfs _between_ those commands to narrow it down more.

Comment: Just before > current->Id_Doctor=id_doc; <, the segmentation fault occurs.                                                         I've erased this things > strcpy(current->Nombre, nombre_doc); strcpy(current->Clave_Acceso, password); strcpy(current->Especialidad, especialida); current->Estado=estado_doc; current=current->next; < , only leaving current->Id_Doctor=id_doc; and it still gives me the segmentation fault.

Comment: So, what Im trying to tell you is that Im doing something wrong when I try to storage the data to the structure...If I erase everything between current->Id bla bla bla , the program runs smoothly(as it gets).

Comment: What is your developer platform (OS, compiler etc)? Using a debugger here would help a _lot_. Unelss you can post your code and a copy of the input file somewhere so that we can take a look.

Comment: Also try checking the value of current. It should not be NULL.

Comment: the output file called md.dat contains the next:

Comment: @thkala hahaha I want to kill myself that was the error, current was = to NULL
How do I give you rep and everything???

Comment: @Ro Schz: I posted a simple answer incorporating most of my comments